# Can Views output only the first vocabulary term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there an easy way in Views to output the first vocabulary term only?

Comment: Do you mean filtering on the first term in a vocabulary, or listing only one term from a term reference with several values?

Comment: For instance if my tags for an article are "music", "song" and "singer", I just want the view to output the term "music" and leave out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the term reference field in your view, and under "Multiple Field Settings" check "Display all values in the same row". You will be presented with further options. You will probably want Display options to be Simple Separator, then change "Display [all] value(s)" to "Display [1] value(s)", apply and save your view.